# How is the Vision able to fly?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron, infinity-stones

In *Age of Ultron*, the individuals who are capable of flight can easily be explained: The Iron Man platforms as well as Ultron use repulsor technology, there is visible combustion creating thrust and maneuvering. Thor's flight isn't as easily explained but it is somewhat understandable how he is essentially being pulled by Mjölnir.

But the Vision appears to have no combustion, no boot jets. Is he using the Mind gem to manipulate gravity?

Comment: a combination of phasing and mental-abilities most likely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The mechanics of the Vision's flight abilities in the Marvel Cinematic Universe has not been officially designated. All we can draw upon is the canon character design from the Earth-616 version of the Vision.

- We have seen the Vision fly effectively in the A:AOU manipulating his movement and controlling his momentum. We cannot say if he has any real speed and this is concurrent with his comic depictions where he is limited to speeds of less than 50 mph.
- Since neither the full range of the Vision's capabilities or the Mind Gem's abilities have been documented in the MCU, we are forced to utilize what we have seen in the canon Marvel Universe as a possible reference until ratified by the writers/editors/producers of the movies.

#### Powers of The Mind Gem

We are introduced to the **[Mind Gem](http://marvel.wikia.com/Mind_Gem)** during the Thanos Quest where it was in the hands of the **[Elder of the Universe](http://marvel.com/universe/Elders_of_the_Universe)** known as **[The Grandmaster](http://marvel.com/universe/Grandmaster)**. The Grandmaster used the Gem to increase his intelligence making him even more formidable in his lifelong pursuit of games and other probability-driven challenges. It did not help him against the Mad Titan, however.

[image]

The Mind Gem in the canon Marvel Universe has rarely been depicted functioning by itself. It can:

- Increase the intelligence of its wielder to superhuman capacities.
- Give its wielder the ability to read the minds of others and translate languages instantly. A user can read and alter the dreams of others. An experienced psychic can manipulate and erect psychic barriers in the user's mind or the minds of others.
- The wielder can perform astral projection, directing their consciousness to appear in other locations, even at great distances.
- It can give the possessor the ability to manipulate and control the minds of people under its influence.
- It has the capacity to give the wielder extreme telekinetic ability limited by their experience manipulating telekinetic powers. The more experience a wielder has, the more they are able to move, lift and control.
- In conjunction with the other Infinity Gems, it may have powers that have not been depicted.

#### Powers of the Vision:

- **[The Vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_%28Marvel_Comics%29)**, in the comics, has an extraordinary set of abilities due to his synthezoid construction. Being an artificial life-form/android of sorts, the Vision possesses multiple superhuman senses—as well as superhuman stamina, reflexes, speed, agility, and strength (even without being at high density).

  - **The Vision also possesses the ability to manipulate his density, which at its lowest allows flight and a ghostly, phasing intangibility, and at its heaviest provides superhuman strength, immovability, and a diamond-hard near invulnerability.**
  - The Solar Jewel on the Vision's forehead absorbs ambient solar energy to provide the needed power for him to function, and he is also capable of discharging this energy as optic beams capable of temperatures from 500 to 30,000 degrees Fahrenheit.
  - In extreme cases he can discharge this same power through the Solar Jewel itself which amplifies its destructive effects considerably, albeit at the cost of losing most of his energy resources.
  - The Vision often uses his ability to alter his density against foes, by phasing an intangible hand through them and then partially re-materializing it—a process he describes as "physical disruption." This effect typically causes great pain and results in incapacitation.
  - The Vision is capable of reaching a density ten times greater than that of depleted uranium and is capable of becoming harder than diamond. On one occasion, the Vision uses this extreme durability to render unconscious the villainous Count Nefaria. **REF: The Handbook of the Marvel Universe - The Vision**

[image]
[image]

**The MCU Vision emulated almost all of these powers flawlessly. It is unlikely he needs the Mind Gem to aid in his flight in any way.**

Comment: Who is the shirtless man with Wanda in the penultimate frame? Is it Cyclops? If so, why is he shirtless?

Comment: The shirtless man is Simon Williams, AKA Wonder Man.